# How do I notate that $1/2$ children do not exist

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Suppose that,

- the average person has $2$  $1/2$ children.
- only whole children exist

It should be straightforward to notate:

- If an average person exists, then that person has two $1/2$ children
- there does not exist $1/2$ a child
- Therefore, the average person does not exist.

However, I can't figure out to notate the $1/2$ child part so that the meaning of $1/2$ is clear. The problem, as I see it is that if whole children exist $(1/1)$ then half children exist $(1/2 + 1/2)$.

How do I convey the idea in notation?

Comment: Why do you want to convey that idea using notation?

Comment: @Bananarama Short version: personal interest. Long version: I'm writing an essay (just for kicks) about reasons to work to improve the lives of people afflicted by a given problem instead of working to improve the lives of the average person afflicted by the problem. E.g. We focus on improving the health of unhealthy people not the health of white/black/female/male people on the grounds that one group "has it worse" - since some in groups who average member "has it better" may have it worse than others in another group whose average member "has it worse".

Comment: And, igven that you want to use notation, it really depends on what notation you are currently using. We can invent lots of notations for this...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm using standard predicate logic, and using fitch notation to construct the proof. But I just need help expressing it in predicate logic.

Comment: So you want to use predicate-logic in a political essay!? Well, good luck with that!

Comment: @Winther it's a philosophy essay.

Comment: I see, but I personally think you'd be better off not mixing in mathematical logic (and especcially proofs) in a philosophical / political essay of the type you mention. You cannot use mathematical logic to prove or disprove anything that matters (sorry logicians) about such questions as you talk about (if you don't cheat). Anyway, hope it turns out good:)

Comment: @Winther Ethicists and philosophers use predicate logic in almost everything. This is not unusual. And thank you for the good wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it like this: "Statistically a person has on average a half child." It is different from your wording. An average person cannot have a half child.

Mathematical formulation:

$x_i:$Number of children of person i

$x_i \in \mathbb N$

$\overline x:$ Average number of children per person.

Comment: Well take the average person to be a collection of the averages of a population. E.g. The average number of children a person has, the average age of a person, the average number of years in prison, average salary. Anyway, I think it's obvious that this person doesn't exist, but s/he is referenced, as though s/he exists, in discourse all the time.

Comment: The person does not exist. Here I agree with you. But it exists the average number of children, which a person of a Country (statistically) has.